# Mac Fails to recognize my Android phone through USB

Tags: adb, usb, connection-issues, macos

I installed ADB via homebrew but running `adb devices` returns an empty list. I also tried `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` but I still fail to find my device here. I don't have EasyUSBTethering issues on my system. After connecting to my iMac, my cell phone starts charging, but fails to start USB debugging even though I have turned both "Develop Mode" and "USB Debugging" on. The version of my MacOS is 10.14.4.

There is no problem with the cable because I can USB Debug with it on my PC.

I know this situation seems awkward. Any possibility is welcomed and please feel free for requesting more relevant information about my devices. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally it turns out to be a cable issue - but very weird! On Windows both USB 3.0 and 2.0 Cables are supported. On Mac, however, only USB 2.0 cables are supported. Initially I was using a 3.0 cable and thus by confirming that everything runs smoothly on PC, I directly denied the possibility of cable issues. I wish my sorrowful experience could help prevent some valueless efforts.